# Different content in multiple css popups

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, popup

Sooo.. I have this html/css popup code.
I want multiple popups in my page, but when I click on another popup, it will only show the content of the first one in the html.
How can I make them show different content?

This is the code:

```
html:
        <div class="box">
        <a class="button" href="#popup1">Click Here</a>
    </div>
    <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
        <div class="popup">
            <h2>Here I am</h2>
            <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
            <div class="content">
                This is the content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Css:

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(4.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  color:black;

}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: red;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;

}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: red;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Just did something similar to Jagzviruz - the popup work, if you create seprate popup divs and assign the ids properly to the opening links. Since your question has got no JavaScript in it, maybe you should remove the jQuery tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is build multiple popup divs, and specify the targets. Sadly, you cannot use the same popup div to display the content, without using javascript.
Here is a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jagzviruz/x73j4a9p/) to demonstrate how you can do this.

```
<div class="box"> 
    <a class="button" href="#popup2">Click Here 2</a>
</div>
<div id="popup2" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Here I am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">This is the content from 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```